# Disable logout confirmation dialogue box in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, logout

I cannot turn off the logout-confirmation box.

Yes, I have set: 
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power suppress_logout_restart_shutdown true

Yes, I have clicked "suppress-logout-restart-shutdown" in the dconf-editor, and yes, I have done the same as root for lightdm (using: sudo -i; xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm; dconf-editor)

Please help, this drives me nuts...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to switch to the lightdm user before running dconf-editor:

```
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
dconf-editor
```